# why node.js bodyParser always returns 'undefined'?

Tags: node.js, undefined, router, body-parser

> In 'app.js' I have

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
```

> 'index.js' full codes

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var mysql = require('mysql');

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('index', { title: 'Here' });
});

router.post('/manager', function(req, res, next) {
    var connection = mysql.createConnection({
        host        : 'localhost',
        user        : req.body.username,
        password    : req.body.password,
        database    : 'shops'
    });
    connection.connect(function(err){
         if(!err)
             res.render('manager', { title: 'Here' });  
         else
             console.log("Error connecting database ...");  
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

> In 'index.html' login form

```
<form id='login' method='post' action='manager'>
    Username<br>
    <input id='username' type='text'><br>
    Password<br>
    <input id='password' type='password'><br>

    <input type='submit' value='Login'>
    <input type='reset' value='Reset'>
</form>
```

- **In index.js line 12-13**

  12. **req.body.username**
  13. **req.body.password**

Everytime I try to parse data from html form, they return 'undefined'. I'm new to node.js scripting. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Documentation for https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser 

This might be your issue...

"This does not handle multipart bodies."

Comment: You should show your client-side form too.

Comment: @mscdex I added the html code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're missing `name` attributes on your `<input>` tags. Add them like:

```html
<form id='login' method='post' action='manager'>
  Username<br>
  <input id='username' name='username' type='text'><br>
  Password<br>
  <input id='password' name='password' type='password'><br>

  <input type='submit' value='Login'>
  <input type='reset' value='Reset'>
</form>
```

Comment: Exactly! Thank you sir.